# MATLAB (R2016a). How are these 2 statements different?

Tags: matlab

```
[theta , J] = gradientDescent(X , Y , theta , alpha , iteratons);
theta , J = gradientDescent(X , Y , theta , alpha , iterations);
```

Running the above two statements gave me different results. The first one gave me the desired one but the second one did not. Why?

**EDIT:**

This is the declaration of the function :

```
function [theta, J_history] = gradientDescent(X, y, theta, alpha, num_iters)
```

Comment: Because the function returns a tuple? See https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html

Answer (score 3):

To specify multiple outputs from a function, you must enclose the output arguments with `[]`. The second statement that you have provided will simply display the value of `theta` and assign the *first* output of `gradientDescent` to `J`

For the sake of an example:

```
a = 1
a, b = rand(10)
```

Is the equivalent of

```
a = 1
a
b = rand(10)
```

If you want two output arguments from a function, you *must* enclose them in `[]` so that they are both assigned.

```
[theta , J] = gradientDescent(X , Y , theta , alpha , iteratons);
```